# Problemas com os print no socket python

Tags: python, socket

eu já estou a horas tentando resolver esse erro, bom... no socket do python eu fiz um programa em que o cliente envia o nome dele e o programa pega o IP e a data e hora que ele enviou e escreve essas informações num arquivo .txt

Mas eu estou com problema nos prints das informações do cliente

Esse é o código do servidor:

```
#SERVIDOR
from socket import *
from time import *

sala = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
sala.bind(('', 58117))
sala.listen()
print('Aguardando Clientes...\n')

while True:
   con, adr = sala.accept()
   
   client_nome = con.recv(1024).decode()
   IP = con.recv(1024).decode()
   data = con.recv(1024).decode()
   hora = con.recv(1024).decode()
   print(f'Nome: {client_nome}')
   print(f'IP: {IP}')
   print(f'Data: {data} | Hora: {hora}')

   with open('/storage/emulated/0/python/pessoas.txt', 'a') as ip:
      ip.write(f'\nPessoa: {client_nome}\nIP: {IP}\n{data}\n')
```

Esse é o do cliente:

```
#CLIENTE
from time import *
from socket import *
from requests import *

dh = localtime()

client = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
client.connect(('', 58117))

client_nome = str(input('Apelido: '))
IP = get('https://api.ipify.org').text

data = str(f'{dh[2]}/{dh[1]}/{dh[0]}')
hora = str(f'{dh[3]}:{dh[4]}')

client.send(client_nome.encode())
client.send(IP.encode())
client.send(data.encode())
client.send(hora.encode())
```

Esse é o resultado com os prints bugados:

```
Aguardando Clientes..


Nome: TESTE PY
IP: THON
Data: 177.107.10 | Hora: 7.24
```

A parte do nome invadiu a área do ip, o ip ficou na parte de data e hora, e a data e hora sumiram kkk eu realmente não sei oque está errado, sou novo no socket, então por favor alguém me ajuda a tirar esse "Bug"

Comment: Tenta acrescentar nesta linha `client.send(client_nome.encode())` um `\n`. Isso deverá fazer com que o socket.send faça um flush...

Comment: Alás, em todas que enviam.

Answer (score 0):

Se você garantir que a mensagem é menor que 1024, isso servirá

### Servidor

```
#SERVIDOR
from socket import *
from time import *

sala = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
sala.bind(('', 58117))
sala.listen()
print('Aguardando Clientes...\n')

while True:
   con, adr = sala.accept()

   dados = con.recv(1024).decode()

   print(dados)

   client_nome, IP, data, hora = dados.split("|")

   print(f'Nome: {client_nome}')
   print(f'IP: {IP}')
   print(f'Data: {data} | Hora: {hora}')

   with open('./pessoas.txt', 'a') as ip:
      ip.write(f'\nPessoa: {client_nome}\nIP: {IP}\n{data}\n')
```

### Cliente

```
#CLIENTE
from time import *
from socket import *
from requests import *

dh = localtime()

client = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
client.connect(('', 58117))

client_nome = str(input('Apelido: '))
IP = get('https://api.ipify.org').text

data = str(f'{dh[2]}/{dh[1]}/{dh[0]}')
hora = str(f'{dh[3]}:{dh[4]}')

client.send((f'{client_nome}|{IP}|{data}|{hora}').encode())
```